# How to fetch a particular row in Greendao db Android

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

Hi i am working with greendao db and need to fetch values from particular column called "datetime" from my database. I need to access the values from that column. Kindly help

My code:

```
 Query query = UserDao.queryBuilder().where(
                    new WhereCondition.StringCondition("_id IN " +
                            "(SELECT _dateTime FROM TABLE_GREENDAO)"))
                    .build();
            List week = query.list();
```

Comment: orm works with objects (rows). you can get access to column only after fetching row which  is object and then get column value as field in this object. you also can select rows with condition of value in datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
return week!=null && week.size()>0 ? week.get(0):null;
```